# What is exactly the function of the 'max_file_uploads' limitation?

Tags: php, security, file-upload

PHP has an ini-setting 'max_file_uploads' that prevents more files than the given number to be uploaded at once. Default is 20, can be changed into anything (I think).

What does this precisely prevent, given that there is also a 'post_max_size' and 'upload_max_filesize' in place? I mean, what security risks am I running into if I would change this limit into something huge like 999, so it gets out of the way, while keeping the other two limits at some sane level?

Comment: If you need to upload large files, not having that limit would allow to flood the server with some million empty files. I can speculate that may be the rationale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of this as defense in depth, an additional layer of protection against generic threats around file uploads.

One that directly comes to mind is an attacker uploading many very small (or 0 byte) files. Those would normally get stored in the temp directory (`/tmp` usually), and on many filesystems there is limit to the number of files in a directory, and a lot of files can also affect filesystem performance.

This is a risk you can decide to accept, or implement other mitigations so this php setting doesn't "get in the way". Quite honestly, in many applications this would likely never cause an issue, but you need to be aware and make an informed decision. In some higher security applications increasing or removing this limitation might not be acceptable.

Comment: Ok, so making it bigger isn't a problem generally, but all the way without would be. Thanks for your answer